# Comparator<File> for "directories-first" order

Tags: java, file, comparator

I'm stumped... Let's say I have this directory tree:

```
{someRoot}/
{someRoot}/bar/
{someRoot}/bar/file1.txt
{someRoot}/foo/
{someRoot}/foo/baz/
{someRoot}/foo/baz/file3.txt
{someRoot}/foo/abracadabra.txt
{someRoot}/foo/file2.txt
{someRoot}/aardvark.txt
{someRoot}/food.txt
{someRoot}/zebra.txt
```

You'll note the ordering. Call this **order1**. At each stage, the directories come first before the files. (**NOTE:**  `bar/file1.txt` comes before `foo`, so on a global basis, the directories do not all come before all the files.)

If I enumerate this directory tree, and then recursively enumerate the subdirectories, I'll get the following `List<File>`, with ordering **order2**.

```
{someRoot}/
{someRoot}/aardvark.txt
{someRoot}/bar/
{someRoot}/foo/
{someRoot}/food.txt
{someRoot}/zebra.txt
{someRoot}/bar/file1.txt
{someRoot}/foo/abracadabra.txt
{someRoot}/foo/baz/
{someRoot}/foo/file2.txt
{someRoot}/foo/baz/file3.txt
```

If I create the straightforward `Comparator<File>`:

```
Comparator<File> fc = new Comparator<File>(){
    @Override public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
};
```

and I sort, I get this ordering (**order3**) from lexicographic ordering:

```
{someRoot}
{someRoot}/aardvark.txt
{someRoot}/bar
{someRoot}/bar/file1.txt
{someRoot}/foo
{someRoot}/food.txt
{someRoot}/foo/abracadabra.txt
{someRoot}/foo/baz
{someRoot}/foo/baz/file3.txt
{someRoot}/foo/file2.txt
{someRoot}/zebra.txt
```

But I don't want this ordering (which has problems: note that `food.txt` comes between directory `foo` and its sub-items), I want **order1**. How can I write a Comparator to get me that?

Comment: What's the rule placing food.txt at that position? Would barista.txt be placed between "/bar/file1.txt" and "/foo/"?

Comment: Order1 is otherwise known as "Depth First".  That phrase might help your search-fu.

Comment: in order1, barista.txt would be placed after both of them. Most specific directories need to be compared first.

Comment: @Kelly: I've never heard of a depth-first comparator, just a depth-first search.

Comment: @Jason: Its used to describe the behavior of recursive parsers that have to traverse a tree, somewhat like what you are doing.  There is 'depth-first' and 'breadth-first'. They describe the choice made between enumerating child-nodes before peer-nodes and vice versa.

Comment: I still don't understand what logic puts food before aardvark and zebra. "aardvark, food, zebra" makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @dagge: you are correct. Typo on my part.

Answer (score 4):

This works in my tests.

```
new Comparator<File>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(File first, File second) {
        if (first.isDirectory() && second.isDirectory())
            return first.compareTo(second);

        if (first.isDirectory())
            return this.compareToFile(first, second);

        if (second.isDirectory())
            return -(this.compareToFile(second, first));

        return this.compareFiles(first, second);
    }

    private int compareFiles(File first, File second) {
        File firstParentFile = first.getParentFile();
        File secondParentFile = second.getParentFile();

        if (isSubDir(firstParentFile, secondParentFile))
            return -1;

        if (isSubDir(secondParentFile, firstParentFile))
            return 1;

        return first.compareTo(second);
    }

    private int compareToFile(File directory, File file) {
        File fileParent = file.getParentFile();
        if (directory.equals(fileParent))
            return -1;

        if (isSubDir(directory, fileParent))
            return -1;

        return directory.compareTo(file);
    }

    private boolean isSubDir(File directory, File subDir) {
        for (File parentDir = directory.getParentFile(); parentDir != null; parentDir = parentDir.getParentFile()) {
            if (subDir.equals(parentDir)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Just one thing, the for loop in isSubDir should read: for (File parentDir = directory.getParentFile(); parentDir != null; parentDir =
                    parentDir.getParentFile()) {

Comment: @dagge I guess that could cause a problem with the way I have compareFiles written (though compareToFiles works either way). Fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This **recursivly** gets the sorted file tree as you like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<File> files = getFileTree(new File("."));

    for (File f : files)
        System.out.println(f);
}

private static List<File> getFileTree(File file) {

    List<File> files = new LinkedList<File>();
    files.add(file);

    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        File[] current = file.listFiles();
        Arrays.sort(current, new Comparator<File>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
                if (o1.isDirectory())
                    return o2.isDirectory() ? o1.compareTo(o2) : -1;
                else if (o2.isDirectory())
                    return 1;

                return o1.compareTo(o2);
            }
        });

        for (File f : current)
            files.addAll(getFileTree(f));
    }

    return files;
}
```

Comment: +1 -- but I'm not sure I want to use that approach; there are several possible sort orders for a GUI table, and I may need to re-sort to achieve the order I want.

Comment: @Jason S: Ah! Now I get what you want.. :)

Comment: Thanks Man You Save Whole Night Work

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**
You have to compare the Base Directory at first level and File name at second level

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class FileComparator implements Comparator<File> {

    @Override
    public int compare(File o1, File o2) {

        int pathCompare = this.getPath(o1).compareTo(this.getPath(o2));
        if (pathCompare != 0) {
            return subPathCompare;
        } else {
            if (o1.isDirectory() && !o2.isDirectory()) {
                return -1;
            } else if (!o1.isDirectory() && o2.isDirectory()) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return o1.compareTo(o2);
            }
        }
    }

    //maybe there is a better way to speparete path and file name, but it works
    private String getPath(File file) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            return file.getParent().toLowerCase();
        } else {
            return file.getPath().toLowerCase();
        }
    }
}
```

If the separation of path and file is nessesary, because if one only do:

```
        if (o1.isDirectory() && !o2.isDirectory()) {
            return -1;
        } else if (!o1.isDirectory() && o2.isDirectory()) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
```

the the result would be not case 1, but an other case where all directorys would be the first items, and the files are the last:

```
  \dir1\
  \dir2\
  \dir3\
  \dir4\
  \dir1\file1\
  \dir1\file2\
  \dir2\file1\
  \dir2\file2\
```

So my solution is to check first if the two compared files belong to the same directory.

- If they do not belong to the same directory, so they are compared by there directory.
- If the belong to the same directory, then the sub directorys are "sorted" "before" the normal files.

Comment: That I know how to do already, but I have no idea how to incorporate it into a working Comparator.

Answer (score 0):

```
Comparator<File> fc = new Comparator<File>(){
        @Override public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
            boolean isFirstDirectory = o1.isDirectory();
            boolean isSecondDirectory = o2.isDirectory();

            if(!isFirstDirectory && !isSecondDirectory) {
                return o1.compareTo(o2);

            } else if (isFirstDirectory && !isSecondDirectory){
                return (int) 1;
            } else if(isSecondDirectory && !isFirstDirectory) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return o1.compareTo(o2);
            }


        }
    };
```

Comment: No, that won't work right. I don't want all directories before all files. At a given parent directory, I want its subdirectories to come before its files.

Answer (score 0):

I did find a way to implement the pseudo-opposite of what I wanted (directories *after* files, haven't checked the edge cases where files and directory names are at the root level).

...And no, it's not trivial to transform this into what I do want, because I'm using lexicographic ordering of directories, which couples the ordering of directories at different levels and the ordering of directories at the same level.

```
static class FileDirectoryPriorityComparator implements Comparator<File>
{
    @Override public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
        if (f1.isDirectory())
        {
            if (f2.isDirectory())
            {
                return f1.compareTo(f2);                        
            }
            else
            {
                return compareDirFile(f1, f2);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (f2.isDirectory())
            {
                return -compareDirFile(f2, f1);
            }
            // f1 and f2 are both files
            else
            {
                return compareFiles(f1, f2);
            }
        }
    }

    private int compareDirFile(File dir, File file) {
        /* 
         * If dir compares differently to file's parent, use that ordering.
         * Otherwise, dir comes before file. 
         */              
        File fparent = file.getParentFile();

        if (fparent == null)
            return -1;

        int i = dir.compareTo(fparent);
        if (i != 0)
            return i;

        return -1;
    }

    private int compareFiles(File f1, File f2) {
        /* 
         * If f1's parent compares differently to f2's parent, use that ordering.
         * Otherwise use default ordering.
         */              
        File fp1 = f1.getParentFile();
        File fp2 = f2.getParentFile();

        if (fp1 == null)
        {
            if (fp2 != null)
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            if (fp2 == null)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else
            {
                int i = fp1.compareTo(fp2);
                if (i != 0)
                    return i;                   
            }
        }           

        return f1.compareTo(f2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course too late. In any case here is a `Comparator` implementation that sorts as asked for in this SO.

```
public class DirectoryBeforeFileComparator implements Comparator<File> {
    @Override
    public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
        if (o1.isDirectory() && !o2.isDirectory()) {
            // directory before non-directory.
            return -1;
        }
        if (!o1.isDirectory() && o2.isDirectory()) {
            // non-directory after directory
            return 1;
        }
        // compare two pathnames lexicographically
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
}
```