# How to sort file names with its type of file in Java

Tags: java, sorting, filefilter

I have a folder from which i can get the all the list of files.

```
File []filesPaths = filePath.listFiles((dir, name) -> !name.equals(".DS_Store"));
```

**filesPaths** contains all the list of files and folders, which i want to sort files comes first and after folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparator<File> for "directories-first" order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440765/comparatorfile-for-directories-first-order) OR even https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32312738/how-to-sort-listfile-to-list-directories-first-and-grouping-files-by-directory has a Java 8 solution.

Answer (score 0):

To sort the array, use [`Arrays.sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-).

To sort directories *last*, identify a directory by calling [`File.isDirectory()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory--), which returns `true` if it's a directory, and use [`Boolean.compare(boolean x, boolean y)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#compare-boolean-boolean-) to sort by boolean value (`false` sorts before `true`).

Using Java 8 lambda expression, it's just one line of code:

```
// Sort directories last
Arrays.sort(filesPaths, (a,b) -> Boolean.compare(a.isDirectory(), b.isDirectory()));
```

If you want to sort directories *first*, simply flip `a` and `b` in the call to `compare()`:

```
// Sort directories first
Arrays.sort(filesPaths, (a,b) -> Boolean.compare(b.isDirectory(), a.isDirectory()));
```